# Post part of Form Data while doing xmlhttp request

Tags: excel, vba, post, xmlhttprequest

In the following code I am trying to use the POST method and I have noticed it is using the Form Data which has a very very long text

```
Sub Test()
Dim http        As New XMLHTTP60
Dim html        As New HTMLDocument
Dim post        As Object
Dim myUrl       As String
Dim postData    As String


myUrl = "https://www.e.gov.kw/sites/kgoArabic/Pages/eServices/PACI/CivilIDStatus.aspx"
postData = "ctl00%24m%24g_cca43156_d33a_4ef1_8782_2c3c7a4eeaf3%24ctl00%24txtCivilID=270022102796"

With http
    .Open "POST", myUrl, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .send postData
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText

    WriteTxtFile html.body.innerHTML
End With

End Sub

Sub WriteTxtFile(ByVal aString As String, Optional ByVal filePath As String = "C:\Users\Future\Desktop\Output.txt")
Dim fso         As Object
Dim fileout     As Object

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fileout = fso.CreateTextFile(filePath, True, True)
fileout.Write aString
fileout.Close
End Sub
```

I am trying to search for ID `270022102796` which is in this part of the form data `ctl00%24m%24g_cca43156_d33a_4ef1_8782_2c3c7a4eeaf3%24ctl00%24txtCivilID=270022102796`.
In the rendered html, I couldn't find the expected output for this entry which should be in the element which ID is `ctl00_m_g_cca43156_d33a_4ef1_8782_2c3c7a4eeaf3_ctl00_lblResult`

Is it possible to use just part of the form data? And if possible why didn't I got the correct HTML document?

- To make the issue clear, I have a solution using IE

  ```
    Sub IDQuery()

   Dim doc As HTMLDocument
   Dim ie As Object
   Dim r As Integer
   Dim i As Integer

   Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

   With ie
    .Visible = True

    For r = 2 To Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
       If r = 2 Then
             .navigate "https://www.e.gov.kw/sites/kgoArabic/Pages/eServices/PACI/CivilIDStatus.aspx"
          Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
          Do: DoEvents: Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

          Set doc = ie.document
          While ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
      End If

      doc.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_cca43156_d33a_4ef1_8782_2c3c7a4eeaf3_ctl00_txtCivilID").Value = Worksheets(1).Cells(r, 1).Value
      doc.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_cca43156_d33a_4ef1_8782_2c3c7a4eeaf3_ctl00_btnSearch").Click

      Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

      Worksheets(1).Cells(r, 2).Value = doc.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_cca43156_d33a_4ef1_8782_2c3c7a4eeaf3_ctl00_lblResult").innerText
  Next r

  ie.Quit
  End With
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: start by using all the params in the body and then remove ones whilst monitoring for correcr response html. Start by removing the params which don't have values in the key value pairs. Then move on to ones that look like might have default values or are of no interest for return e.g. _maintainWorkspaceScrollPosition . But do include __VIEWSTATE and __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR and __EVENTVALIDATION and ctl00$m$g_cca43156_d33a_4ef1_8782_2c3c7a4eeaf3$ctl00$txtCivilID and ctl00$m$g_cca43156_d33a_4ef1_8782_2c3c7a4eeaf3$ctl00$btnSearch as a minimum. Leave the encoding of body to happen in the send.

Comment: The __ variables may need collection from prior GET. Cookies may be required.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. In fact I didn't get what you are trying to tell me. I will add a solution that uses IE so as to make it clear

Comment: We can discuss when I am free later

Comment: Thank you very much. Take your time. Have a nice time